# Implementation of pure virtual function via inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

I have the following situation:

```
class Fork {
    public:
        virtual void use() = 0;
};

class Spoon {
    public:
        virtual void use() = 0;
};

class SilverSpoon : public Spoon {
    public:
        virtual void use() { }
};

class SilverSpork : public SilverSpoon, public Fork {
    public:
        using SilverSpoon::use;
};
```

I was hoping that the pure virtual function `Fork::use` would be defined by `SilverSpoon::use` in `SilverSpork`. However, I get

```
error: cannot declare variable ‘spork’ to be of abstract type ‘SilverSpork’
note:  because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘SilverSpork’:
note:  virtual void Fork::use()
```

Is there a way to solve this without having to add

```
virtual void use() {
    SilverSpoon::use();
}
```

to `SilverSpork`?

Comment: But `SilverSpoon` doesn't inherit from `Fork`. Its `use()` doesn't redefine `Fork's`. Try with `SilversPoon: public Fork` and `SilverSpork: public SilverSpoon`.

Comment: I forgot `: public Spoon`. Fixed it.

Comment: @Lucas You should not modify your original post to fix the problem otherwise readers who see it later on may not understand. Add an edit section explaining the fix.

Comment: @AdrC.S., the problem is a silver spoon is not a fork. In my code, `Fork` also implements other methods which I don't want to have in `SilverSpoon`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no inherent connection between `Fork` and `Spoon`, and the fact that they both have a virtual function named `use` doesn't make one. However, if you add a new class, say, `Utensil` that defines a pure virtual function `use()`, and derive both `Fork` and `Spoon` from it as a virtual base, you've got a connection. With that, the class `SilverSpork` **will** pick up the implementation of `SilverSpoon::use` as the overrider for `use` in its direct base `Fork`. This is known as "dominance".

```
class Utensil {
public:
    virtual void use() = 0;
};

class Spoon : public virtual Utensil {
public:
    virtual void use() = 0; // or can omit this, relying on Utensil
};

class Fork : public virtual Utensil {
public:
    virtual void use() = 0; // or can omit this, relying on Utensil
};

class SilverSpoon : public Spoon {
public:
    void use() { }
};

class SilverSpork : public SilverSpoon, public Fork {
}; // OK: SilverSpoon::use overrides Fork::use
```

Answer (score 2):

`Fork::use()` and `Spoon::use()` are two different methods with same name which are extending to `SilverSpork`.

Compiler expects both of them to be implemented. It's just a name conflicting not overriding nor overloading. A possibility is inheriting Fork and Spoon from a base virtual class:

```
class Object {
    public:
        virtual void use() = 0;    
};

class Fork : virtual public Object {
};

class Spoon: virtual public Object {
};

class SilverSpoon : public Spoon {
    public:
        virtual void use() { cout << "SilverSpoon" << endl; }
};

class SilverSpork : public SilverSpoon, public Fork {
    public:
        using SilverSpoon::use;
};
```

Diagram:

```
                                    +---------------+
                                    |    Object     |
                                    +---------------+
                                      ^           ^
                                      |           |
                                      |           |
                                      |           |
                       +---------------+         +---------------+
                       |    Spoon      |         |     Fork      |
                       +---------------+         +---------------+
                               ^                  ^
                               |                  |
                               |                  |
                               |                  |
                       +---------------+          |
                       |  SilverSpoon  |          |
                       +---------------+          |
                                      ^           |
                                      |           |
                                      |           |
                                      |           |
                                   +---------------+
                                   |  SilverSpork  |
                                   +---------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you use multiple inheritance, you actually inherit two different abstract `use` methods and you have to override *both* of them in your child.

The first question you need to ask yourself is why a `SilverSpork` has the same `use` behavior as a `SilverSpoon`. If it  really does, I can't believe I'm going to suggest this, but you could possibly solve this problem by using diamond inheritance with a new virtual base:

```
class Utinsil
{
    public:
        virtual void use() = 0;
};

class Fork : public virtual Utinsil {
};

class Spoon : public virtual Utinsil {
};

class SilverSpoon : public Spoon {
    public:
        virtual void use() { }
};

class SilverSpork : public SilverSpoon, public Fork {
};

int main()
{
    SilverSpork silver_spork;
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `using` in `SilverSpork`.